# Installing lvm on luks by "something else"

Tags: boot, lvm, luks, initramfs

I never succeeded installing Ubuntu by choosing something else option. Because I want to change some stuff than the default ones. e.g. partition size, file system to btrfs, not making swap partition, making home partition. 
I just want to make two partitions: one ESP, and one encrypted luks container and NOT making a separated /boot partition. 
Every time I try to install in this scheme, I fail. Can anyone please guide me what should I do? Sometimes installation will fail because of error in installing of grub, and sometimes if installation successful, I don't know what to do before restart; edit crypttab, what and how to add or edit kernel initram modules (on Arch it's obvious to do what)

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible. If you have LUKS partition, you **need** separate /boot. How should your system know what to do (e.g. boot the loader to unlock the disk)?

Comment: I tested this on arch and opensuse, worked without problem. As answer to your question, "grub_enable_cryptodisk" in the grub conf file will tell grub to load kernel from encrypted partition. Ubuntu installer won't let to first install grub then change it's config.

Comment: Thanks, I never heard of it, but it seems you are right. Found a blog post from someone having success doing that for Mint https://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/

Comment: I tested it but not successful. The main problem here is the installer is made to just expect a separated boot partition. Today encryption is a must for privacy. The only reason I don't use Ubuntu for now, is this problem.

Comment: @pLumo if you can have a test on a VM, do this favor to me please and tell me results. I have tested again today without success. The Pavel kogan roadway. Thanks